# Proof review- Every sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has monotone subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

I would like to know if my proof is correct. **I'm worried that I may have broken some rules of constructive proofs** (e.g. providing a construction with infinite steps). Also, please excuse my abuse of notation when I use $(x_{n_k})$ to denote a "sequence" that may not have infinitely many terms.

*Proof.*

Step 1) We'll construct a non-decreasing subsequence $(x_{n_k})$. Let $x_1 \in (x_{n_k})$. Next, *test* each term in $(x_n)$: assume $x_j$ has been tested. Assume $x_k$ is the greatest member in $(x_{n_k})$ so far. If $$x_{j+1} \geq x_k$$ then append $x_{j+1}$ to the subsequence $(x_{n_k})$. Then test $x_{j+2}$ and so on. **If all $x_n$, $n > j$, "fail" the test (cannot be appended to the subsequence), then move to 2.**

Step 2) We'll construct a non-increasing subsequence $(x_{n_k})$. Let $x_1 \in (x_{n_k})$. Next, *test* each term in $(x_n)$: assume $x_j$ has been tested. Assume $x_k$ is the smallest member in $(x_{n_k})$ so far. If $$x_{j+1} \leq x_k$$ then append $x_{j+1}$ to the subsequence $(x_{n_k})$. Then test $x_{j+2}$ and so on. **Both steps cannot "fail" (because of trichotomy)- or else we get the contradiction that $(x_n)$ has finitely many terms.**

This process will produce a monotone subsequence. If Step 1 fails, the subsequence is decreasing. If not, it is increasing.

Comment: Yes, it goes something like this..

Comment: You can make this rigorous by using the Recursion Theorem. PS: Don't begin saying "Let $x_1\in (x_{n_k})$" since $(x_{n_k})$ doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @DanielEscudero Which recursion theorem do you mean?

Comment: Also, this seems at least essentially correct. The short description seems to be the following. If there's no non-increasing subsequence, then by removing finitely many terms you have a non-decreasing subsequence. If there's no non-decreasing subsequence, then by removing finitely many terms you have a non-increasing subsequence. If both exist then you're already done. This description isn't constructive (it is essentially a proof by contradiction), but your algorithm "constructifies" it.

Comment: @Ian Given a function $g:X\to X$ and an element $a\in X$, there exists a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to X$ such that $f(0)=a$ and $f(n+1)=g(f(n))$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this approach:
The sequence is either

1) Unbounded : then there is a clear monotone subsequence: given any $m$,

there must be infinitely-many terms larger/smaller than $m$

2)Bounded: Then you can use the LimSup or LimInf . These are limit points, so they have
convergent susequences.